# Transposing unstructured rows in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, transpose

I have a dataset like this:

```
category                 UK             US           Germany  
sales                    100000        48000        36000 
budget                   50000         20000        14000
n_employees              300           123          134  
diversified              1             0            1   
sustainability_score     22.8          38.9         34.5
e_commerce               37000         7000         11000   
budget                   25000         10000        10000
n_employees              18            22           7  
traffic                  150 mil       38 mil       12500 
subsidy                  33000         26000        23000  
budget                   14000         6000         6000
own_marketing            0             0            1
```

In the dataset, sales variable corresponds to sales from the head quarter.
`e_commerce` is sales of the `e-commerce` and `budget` right after `e_commerce` is actually the budget of `e_commerce` section of the company. Same also applies to `subsisdy`, `subsidy` variable corresponds to sales of the `subsidy` and the `budget` variable after `subsidy` is the budget of the `subsidy`. I want to convert dataset to something like this (if we take UK as an example):

```
UK_main_sales UK_main_budget ... UK_e_commerce_sales UK_e_commerce_budget ...
100000        500000             37000               250000
```

and so on. I tried to do classify variables from different departments by tracking the `budget`  variable as it always comes right after the departant but I was not successful. 
Full list of variables for UK should be like this:

```
UK_main_sales
UK_main_budget
UK_main_n_employees
UK_main_diversified
UK_main_sustainability_score 
UK_e_commerce (we could also add sales but I think it is simpler without sales)
UK_e_commerce_budget
UK_e_commerce_n_employees
UK_e_commerce_traffic
UK_subsidy
UK_subsidy_budget
UK_subsidy_own_marketing
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think need:

```
#get boolean mask for rows for split
mask = df['category'].isin(['subsidy', 'e_commerce'])

#create NaNs for non match values by where
#replace NaNs by forward fill, first NaNs replace by fillna
#create mask for match values by mask and replace by empty string
#join together 
df['category'] = (df['category'].where(mask).ffill().fillna('main').mask(mask).fillna('') 
                   + '_' + df['category']).str.strip('_')

#reshape by unstack 
df = df.set_index('category').unstack().to_frame().T
#flatten MultiIndex
df.columns = df.columns.map('_'.join)
```

---

```
print (df)
  UK_main_sales UK_main_budget UK_main_n_employees UK_main_diversified  \
0        100000          50000                 300                   1   

  UK_main_sustainability_score UK_e_commerce UK_e_commerce_budget  \
0                         22.8         37000                25000   

  UK_e_commerce_n_employees UK_e_commerce_traffic UK_subsidy  \
0                        18               150 mil      33000   

             Germany_main_n_employees  \
0              ...                                   134   

  Germany_main_diversified Germany_main_sustainability_score  \
0                        1                              34.5   

  Germany_e_commerce Germany_e_commerce_budget Germany_e_commerce_n_employees  \
0              11000                     10000                              7   

  Germany_e_commerce_traffic Germany_subsidy Germany_subsidy_budget  \
0                      12500           23000                   6000   

  Germany_subsidy_own_marketing  
0                             1  

[1 rows x 36 columns]
```

Comment: thank you very much, how could I also add "main" to the first variables and subsidy and e-commerce to other ones ?

Comment: oops, give me a sec

Comment: Do you want change names only for `budget`s ?

Comment: Oh, no for all of them

Comment: @edyvedy13 - It seems I ma lost. :( Sorry. What is expected output for more columns (maybe next 6) ?

Comment: Let me edit the question, thank you very much for taking your time out

Comment: @edyvedy13 - Thank you for patience, now is answer what you need.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I accepted it but in some csv files they use ecommerce instead of e_commerce or  subsidy23 subsidy_23 instead of just subsidy... Only common thing is budget is always budget and right after those categories. If I ask you to revise the answer it will be too much ?

Comment: @edyvedy13 - I  think need check by substrings, so change mask in solution from `mask = df['category'].isin(['subsidy', 'e_commerce'])` to `mask = (df['category'] == 'e_commerce') | df['category'].str.contains('subsidy')`

Comment: @jezreal I see, but sometimes there even weirder, they call e_commerce, online_business. There are too many csv files. I know, I should have mentioned it earlier...

Comment: @edyvedy13 - Then need `mask = df['category'].str.contains('subsidy|e_commerce')`